# Make new partition on Mac OS

Tags: macos, usb, partitioning

I've put a Chromium OS image onto a USB stick. It takes up 2GB of the 4GB available. I want to allocate the rest of the 4GB to a FAT partition for general storage. The machine I'm using is a Mac (running OS X 10.4) and when I try to use Disk Utility to create a new partition it says it'll wipe the other 2 that are already on there. Is there a way I can make this new partition in OS X without wiping the others? If I were doing it under Linux, I'd use cfdisk or similar and it wouldn't wipe existing partitions...

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of a free solution on OSX, but [iPartition](http://www.coriolis-systems.com/iPartition.php) should be able to do it for a small fee ($45 US).

Comment: Paying for software? Whatever next! But yeah, it would be an option if I were doing this a lot rather than just once off and then only for fun...

Comment: Fair enough. Good luck finding a solution, and be sure to let us know when you do!

Answer (score 1):

Try [GParted](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/) running from a [live CD](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/livecd.php); tutorial [here](http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/gparted.html#mozTocId335513).  Needless to say, back up your data first.

Comment: Yeah, I could just boot into Chromium and do that anyway - I was wondering if there was a non-destructive way of doing it from within Mac OS... as much out of curiosity as anything else.

Comment: What I meant to say is I think GParted *can* resize non-destructively.

Comment: I don't need to resize anything though, just create a new partition. I did it in Linux in the end, although for some reason I still can't view the new partition in Windows or Mac... it's "inactive" apparently, whatever that means.